# Update object in array of Mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following model schema:

```
{
  _id: foo
  cart: {
    items: [
      { 
        id: number
        name: string,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to find the document by its id, then update the `name` value of the object in the `items` array which has another specified id.

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
Order.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    "_id": orderId,
    "cart.items": {
      $elemMatch: {
        id: itemId,
      }
    },
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "cart.items.$.name": name,
   },
 },
);
```

This query finds the right document, but does not update it correctly. What is the correct way do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
const order = await Order.findOneAndUpdate({
    "_id": orderId,
    "cart.items.id": itemId,
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "cart.items.$.printUrl": printUrl,
    },
  },
});
```

or

```
const order = await Order.findById(orderId);
const cartItems = order!.cart.items;
const itemIndex = cartItems.findIndex((i) => i.id === itemId);
const item = cartItems.filter((i) => i.id === itemId)[0];
item.name = name
cartItems[itemIndex] = item;
order!.cart.items = cartItems;
order!.save();
```